# Loop is sending email to first record?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a code that goes through all the records and checks which check box are CHECKED [True] for all users,
It then sends emails to those people based on their qualification status,

Now when I look at the log file I can see that the loop is parsing through all the records that are checked,

But all the emails get sent to my account email!
Not the users

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {



public PageReference sendnotes() {




 for (Inquery__c inquery: [SELECT Email__c,First_Name__c,Institution__c,Last_Name__c,Quilification__c, OwnerID FROM Inquery__c  WHERE Download__c = True]){

             system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,inquery.Email__c);

   String[] toAddresses = new String[] {inquery.email__c}; 
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


   mail.setTargetObjectId(inquery.OwnerID);
   mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
   mail.setUseSignature(false);
   mail.setBccSender(false);
   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

    if(inquery.Quilification__c == 'Qualified') {
      EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Invitation_to_register_for_Training'];
      mail.setTemplateId(et.id);


        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
       Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   

  }



if(inquery.Quilification__c == 'Disqualified') {
          EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Ineligible_course_candidate'];
          mail.setTemplateId(et.id);


       Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   
  }  

   if(inquery.Quilification__c == 'Inexperienced') {
      EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Inexperienced_course_candidate'];
      mail.setTemplateId(et.id);

       Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   
  }




}


    return null;
}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you are ever setting the ToAddress.  So I'm guessing it defaults to the owner of the targetObject, which I am guessing is you.  Try setting the ToAddress

```
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

Comment: Yes, yes, just fixed it,

Comment: But thanks for your response, appreciate it

Comment: Oh, but I also get an email, as the object owner, do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: If you don't want the owner to get the email, you need to not set the targetObjectID

Comment: Check this out http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

Comment: Glad to help out